# Polars - filling nulls in a column based on values from another

Tags: python, python-polars

I've been trying to learn Polars and one thing I do with Pandas I still couldn't find out how to do is to fill nulls from a column using a dictionary to compare the values in another column. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[np.nan,2,3,np.nan,5],
                  "b":[1,2,3,4,5],
                  })

dictionary={1:1,
           2:4,
           3:6,
           4:8,
           5:10}

df["a"]=df["a"].fillna(df["b"].map(dictionary))
```

This would result the following DataFrame:

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1.0 | 1 |
| 2.0 | 2 |
| 3.0 | 3 |
| 8.0 | 4 |
| 5.0 | 5 |

So my question is: How can I do something similar using Polars? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way, using `when` and `map_dict`:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [None, 2, 3, None, 5],
        "b": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    }
)

dictionary = {1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 8, 5: 10}

df.with_columns(
    a=pl.when(pl.col("a").is_null())
    .then(pl.col("b").map_dict(dictionary))
    .otherwise(pl.col("a"))
)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! I tried upvoting your answer but it didn't count, sorry.
One thing I noticed is how in Pandas, because the nans are treated as float because of Numpy, the column ends up being float and we need to change its type to int if necessary, while in Polars it ends up as int. Very nice :)

Comment: @GabrielZinato You can also pass it directly to `.fill_null` similar to the pandas example. `.with_columns(pl.col("a").fill_null(pl.col("b").map_dict(dictionary)))`

Comment: You know, I thought of `fill_null` but I misread the `Any` typing in the docs as not including `pl.Expr`. Whoops!

Comment: @jqurious That works pretty well too! Thank you very much!